# Подсчет количества значений

Tags: php

Есть массив элементов вида:

```
NAME|DATE|CHECK

Name  - название
Data  - дата добавления
Check - Прошло проверку или нет.
```

Нужно вывести день и сколько элементов в этот день прошли проверку.

Например:

```
TEST1|21 мая|Y
TEST2|21 мая|Y
TEST2|21 мая|Y
TEST3|21 мая|N
TEST4|21 мая|Y
TEST5|1 мая|Y
TEST6|1 мая|Y
TEST7|1 мая|Y
TEST8|1 мая|N
```

Должно вывести:

> 21 мая = 4
>   1 мая = 3

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй вот так.

```
    // Data
$data = "TEST1|21 мая|Y
        TEST2|21 мая|Y
        TEST2|21 мая|Y
        TEST3|21 мая|N
        TEST4|21 мая|Y
        TEST5|1 мая|Y
        TEST6|1 мая|Y
        TEST7|1 мая|Y
        TEST8|1 мая|N";

// Data statistic
$stat = [];

// Parse data line per line
foreach( preg_split( "/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $data ) as $line ){

    // Parse line for get test name, date and result
    $lineData = explode( '|', $line);
    if( isset( $lineData[1], $lineData[2] ) ) {
        $testDate = $lineData[1];
        $testResult = $lineData[2];

        // Check is test positive result
        if( $testResult == 'Y' ) {
            if( !isset( $stat[ $testDate] ) ) {
                $stat[ $testDate] = 0;
            }

            // Increment positive result test grouped by date
            $stat[$testDate]++;
        }
    }
}

print_r( $stat );
```

`print_r( $stat );` выдаст такой результат

```
Array
(
    [21 мая] => 4
    [1 мая] => 3
)
```

Comment: Вообще, с точки зрения оформления кода, мне этот ответ нравится больше. Наличие валидации и комментариев - вообще супер. +, ес-но. Хотя, чуток внимательнее к ТЗ :)

Comment: Почему-то выводит не все значения, а всего 8 и 

$stat = [];

Нельзя так.

Comment: почему нельзя $stat = []; ? Вы используете php 5.3 и ниже?

Comment: Получается, что да. Но меня больше интересует почему не выводит больше 8.

Comment: А что именно 8 должно быть ?

Comment: Должно быть больше, записей с "Y" - 15

Comment: Если возможно весь список элементов покажите пожалуйста ? Для вашего примера описанного выше - вроде нормально работает!

Comment: Спасибо, все правильно, это был мой фейл.

Answer (score 2):

```
$raw_data = array(
    "TEST1|21 мая|Y",
"TEST2|21 мая|Y",
"TEST2|21 мая|Y",
"TEST3|21 мая|N",
"TEST4|21 мая|Y",
"TEST5|1 мая|Y",
"TEST6|1 мая|Y",
"TEST7|1 мая|Y",
"TEST8|1 мая|N",
);

$passed = array();
foreach ($raw_data as $str){
    list($testname,$date,$is_passed) = explode('|',$str);
    if($is_passed=='Y'){
        if(!isset($passed[$date])){
            $passed[$date] = 0;
        }
        $passed[$date]+=1;
    }
}

foreach ($passed as $date=>$amount){
    print $date.' = '.$amount.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для подобных задач очень удобно использовать map/reduce подход. Этот путь позволит сделать код максимально выразительным. В PHP для этих целей служит функиция [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php). Код с ее использованием может выглядеть, например, так:

```
$raw_data = array(
    "TEST1|21 мая|Y",
    "TEST2|21 мая|Y",
    "TEST2|21 мая|Y",
    "TEST3|21 мая|N",
    "TEST4|21 мая|Y",
    "TEST5|1 мая|Y",
    "TEST6|1 мая|Y",
    "TEST7|1 мая|Y",
    "TEST8|1 мая|N",
);

$result = array_reduce($raw_data, function($carry, $item) {
    list(, $date, $check_result) = explode('|', $item);

    if (!array_key_exists($date, $carry)) {
        $carry[$date] = 0;
    }

    if ($check_result === 'Y') {
        $carry[$date]++;
    }

    return $carry;
}, array());

var_dump($result);
```

Рабочий [пример](http://ideone.com/RXaYaO) на IDE One.

Answer (score 1):

У меня так получилось:

```
$data = array(
"TEST1|21 мая|Y",
"TEST2|21 мая|Y",
"TEST2|21 мая|Y",
"TEST3|21 мая|N",
"TEST4|21 мая|Y",
"TEST5|1 мая|Y",
"TEST6|1 мая|Y",
"TEST7|1 мая|Y",
"TEST8|1 мая|N",);

for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

    $data[$i] = explode("|", $data[$i]);

    if($data[$i][2] == "Y") 
        $result[] = $data[$i][1];
}

$result = array_count_values($result);

foreach($result as $value => $count)
    echo $value . " => " . $count . "\r\n";
```

Результат:

```
21 мая => 4
1 мая => 3
```